# Retrieve ForeignKey from views before saving in DJANGO

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views, django-queryset

How can i retrieve the foreign key from the form child relationship, save it at the same time that I am saving the parent information on the same page.

I am currently working with two forms, the Parent and the child. The logic of the page is saving the name of a book and the name of the course it contains.

Ex: Book = "Learn data structure and algorithms", 
    Language = "Python"

models.py

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    entity_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='users')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Entities"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.entity_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('snippets:password', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Password(models.Model):
    password_name = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=False)
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='passwords')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.password_name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from snippets.models import Entity, Password

class EntityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = ('entity_name',)


class PasswordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Password
        fields = ('password_name',)
```

views.py

```
def password_creation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_one = EntityForm(request.POST)
        form_two = PasswordForm(request.POST)
        if form_one.is_valid():
            entity_form = form_one.save(commit=False)
            entity_form.owner = request.user
            entity_form.save()
            password_form = form_two.save(commit=False)
            # HERE : what is the right way to retrieve name from PK
            # owner is not part the Password table field therefore
            # need to be changed to 'password_name'or 'entity'
            # then, how to retrieve the field from the view??
            password_form.owner = request.user
            password_form.save()
            return redirect('snippets:entity')

    else:
        form_one = EntityForm()
        form_two = PasswordForm() 


    context = {
        'form_one':form_one,
        'form_two':form_two,
    }

    return render(request, 'snippets/create-password.html', context)
```

I have tried the codes above. The problem is that Django is saving the name of the "Book" but not the name of the "Language" in the database. The system also breaks and return this message : `NOT NULL constraint failed: snippets_password.entity_id.`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Traceback error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/password_change/snippets/views.py", line 67, in password_creation
    password_form.save()
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1280, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: snippets_password.entity_id
```

Comment: you're not showing the model with snippets_password or how it is accessed. show full traceback please

Comment: I have updated the full traceback above. I believe the problem is to properly retrieve the name from the PK relation. Please look above where it says ```# HERE : what is the right way to retrieve name from PK
            language_form.owner = request.user``` owner (does exist in Language table therefore)must be changed to ```request."book"``` then the right way to retrieve the field. which is what i am struggling with now.

Comment: This is where it is failing:  `File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/password_change_test/password_change/snippets/views.py", line 67, in password_creation
    password_form.save()`

Comment: The traceback does not at all match your code. It shows that it is failing on calling `password_form.save()`. You don't have anything called that in the code you've posted. Please show the actual failing code otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: Daniel, i have updated everything. Do you have any idea how to solve this?? here is what i receive from the terminal ```Exception Value: 
NOT NULL constraint failed: snippets_password.entity_id```. Please read my personal  comments in the view above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagnosis is not at all correct. Password doesn't have an owner field, or in fact any relation with User. Its relationship is with Entity, and the error clearly states that it is the entity or that is missing. So you just have to assign the Entity you just created:

```
    if form_one.is_valid() and form_two.is_valid():
        entity = form_one.save(commit=False)
        entity.owner = request.user
        entity.save()
        password = form_two.save(commit=False)
        password.entity = entity
        password.save()
```

Note, I added a check that that form_two is valid, and also renamed the objects: the result of calling form.save is not a form, but an instance of the model.

Comment: "GENIUS".Thank you so much.